# How to play audio file on app startup

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to play a sound at app startup, and then give the user the chance to pause the sound through a "stop" button. How can I do that?

My actual code is:

```
player1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
          initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
          [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Startsound" ofType:@"m4a"]]error:nil];
player1.numberOfLoops=-1;
[player1 prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: This is very poorly formatted, with little detail and no sign of prior research. -1

Comment: very poor question, please be clear what you want exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As twisted this question was, I did get he was trying to say.

This is how you do it. In your v1AppDelegate.h file add

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface v1AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *myAudioPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *myAudioPlayer;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Now in your v1AppDelegate.m file add this

```
#import "v1AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@implementation v1AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

@synthesize myAudioPlayer;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //start a background sound
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Startsound" ofType: @"m4a"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];    
    myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
    [myAudioPlayer play];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

If you wish to stop or start this music from anywhere else in your code then simply add this

```
#import "v1AppDelegate.h"    
- (IBAction)stopMusic
    {
        v1AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.myAudioPlayer stop];
    }


    - (IBAction)startMusic
    {
        v1AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.myAudioPlayer play];
    }
```